# How to replace unwanted character extra quote in list

Tags: python, list

```
l2=[{'entities': ['(183,187,"PADS"),(391,400,"BRAKE JOB"), 
       (378,383,"FRONT")']}]
```

what I tried is this by converting to string but converting back to list sucks

```
l2 = str(l2).replace("['",'[').replace("']",']')
```

what I need

```
l2=[{'entities': [(183,187,"PADS"),(391,400,"BRAKE JOB"),(378,383,"FRONT")]]
```

removing that single quotes surrounding

```
[(183,187,"PADS"),(391,400,"BRAKE JOB"),(378,383,"FRONT")]
```

I am clueless on replacing that with re.sub and have a list without that single quotes.

Comment: Why do you have a *string representation of a comma separated list of tuples* in the first place? Can't you change that somewhere further up…?

Comment: I got this data from upstream where I don't have control, maybe it is comma separated fields in pandas data frame where they converted to list and send the  file across (my guess)

Comment: Can you give an example of the input data?  You may need to use something like [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) or [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: You trying to remove python syntax, not string.. all strong parts are inside those single qoutes.. and you probably accidentally surrounded it with list soit is now a list containing 1 str

Comment: And its not so clear what is your expected output.. a string or A dict?

Comment: List is my expected output for example to simplify problem list=[' (12,13,"abc"),(15,10,"cde")']   .. whole tuple which is represented as string should be separated to what I need is list =[(12,13,"abc"),(15,10,"cde")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the value for `entities` to a string that can be treated as a list with `|` being the divider.

Then for each element divided by `|`,  contains a sub_list which are separated by commas `,`, then just create a list of these, where you take a string or integer depending if the value can be an integer `isdigit()`

```
l2 = [{'entities': ['(183,187,"PADS"),(391,400,"BRAKE JOB"), (378,383,"FRONT")']}]

list_string = l2[0]['entities'][0].replace("),",'|').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(" ",'').replace('"','')

a = [tuple([int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in i.split(',')]) for i in list_string.split('|')]
l2[0]['entities'] = a

print(l2)

>>> [{'entities': [(183, 187, 'PADS'), (391, 400, 'BRAKEJOB'), (378, 383, 'FRONT')]}]
```

Comment: What if any of the strings happen to contain "|"…? And this could all be simplified a lot with `ast.literal_eval`…

Comment: He didn't say there would be, but "|" can be changed to any unique identifier. @deceze